# How to schedule method on call

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler

How to configure method to be scheduled by calling method. What I exactly mean. Adding annotation `@Scheduled`, method is calling from start application.

I want to run this method with `schedule` (eg. every 2 minutes) but only if **program call this method otherwise this method should not be scheduled**.

Maybe there is another way to do that? Another annotation? If not, how to configure this?

Comment: Then you can use scheduler on caller method.

Comment: @PawanTiwari can you give an example?

Comment: Solution is not so long that it would be an answer, however, you can use the @schedule annotation on your caller method, on which you want to get response from calling method.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of Spring's [TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler-implementations) implementation.

```
//Somewhere define the desired scheduler.

@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler
      = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix(
      "ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}

// define the task you want to run
class RunnableTask implements Runnable{
    private String message;

    public RunnableTask(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(new Date()+" Runnable Task with "+message
          +" on thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}


// to schedule:
taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RunnableTask("Fixed Rate of 2 seconds") , 2000);
```

Credits to [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler)

The main idea is to have some kind of Scheduler defined in the ApplicationContext (i.e. in form of a bean). Then in your logic (where you want to submit the repeating task) you Autowire this executor and submit the task.

Alternatively if the expression you want to run is stateless you don't necessarily need to have a class implementing the `Runnable`, but you can write it as a lambda expression.